# GMP IMPORT/EXPORT

Tags: import, export, biginteger, gmp, sign

I have a problem with **import/export** GMP function.
I try to convert a negative and positive Big Integer but when i work with negative number
i lose the sign.
Are there example about it?

Export:

```
                    int mydim = (mpz_sizeinbase(c, 2) +7)/ 8;
                    myb =  ( char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * mydim);
                    count = (size_t*) malloc(sizeof(size_t));

                    if(mpz_sgn(c)>=0){
                    mpz_export((void *) myb, count, 1, sizeof( char), 1, 0, c);
                            }
                            else{
                    mpz_add_ui(c,c,1);
                    mpz_export((void*)myb, count, 1, sizeof( char), 1, 0, c);
                    for(int i =0;i<=mydim;i++){ //This could be done more effectively
                            myb[i]=~myb[i];
                    }
                    }
```

Import:

```
            mpz_import(s, *count, 1, sizeof(myb[0]), 1, 0, myb);
            int sign = myb[0] < 0?-1:1;
            if(sign == -1)
                    mpz_neg(s,s);
```

Comment: How is `myb` declared?  If it is a `char *`, check to see whether `char` is signed or unsigned on your platform.

Comment: char is signed. if i use char in my application the result is always negative. if i use unsigned char the result is always positive

Answer (score 1):

The [mpz_export documentation](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Import-and-Export.html#index-mpz_005fexport-455) says:

> The sign of op is ignored, just the absolute value is used.

Answer (score 0):

compute complement of myb,and don't forget the sign bit for negative number.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).